# Selenium 2.39 Standalone with Firefox 27/26 Not Starting Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-12.04, selenium-webdriver

I am using Firefox 27 (previously 26) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with a Tomcat application with the Selenium stand alone server 2.39 (latest form Maven) including in the application.   Everything works fine with Chrome but i would prefer to use Firefox, which cannot work.   The Firefox is installed from the standard distributions using xvfb.   Again, all the setup is fine as Chrome works, but when i try to use firefox with the following code:

WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
webDriver.get("www.google.com");

When i take a screen shot of the xvfb, i see a window with the following error:
"Your firefox profile cannot be loaded.  It may be missing or inaccessible".

The webDriver.get("www.google.com") just hangs and does not ever return.

The same code works fine on my development machine, Mac OSX.

I've tried to downgrade firefox and to no avail, same issue.   Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: My Selenium Version is the latest, 2.39.   It did not work with Firefox 26, or i downgraded a few prior versions and it did not work there with the exact same issue.   What bindings would you like?   I'll be more than happy to give any information needed....

Comment: Yes, it is Java bindings

Comment: Just give a try by restarting your machine. I've faced this issue recently. Reinstalling firefox not worked but after restarting my mac it started working. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue.   When running in Ubuntu under Tomcat, the Tomcat instance is run with a root user (tomcat7) when installed from the standard distros.   The issue was, which was pointed to me by Mourasman's response, was Firefox wants to create a .cache/mozilla directory.   This is not possible with a root user.   In order to fix this on the Ubuntu machine, I had to run Tomcat as a "real" user on the system with a home directory that allowed Firefox to create the cache directories it wants (even though Selenium gives it its own profile).

I had trouble doing this using the Ubuntu tomcat distro (I know there is a user and group field in /etc/default/tomcat7) but i could never get it to work.  When i changed the user, which i'm assuming has to do with permissions, it never did work.

So i ended up downloading the source from Tomcat and starting Tomcat manually.....

Hope this helps anyone else who is trying to use Firefox in Selenium in a Tomcat application.

Thanks Mourasman for the pointer on the .cache directory....

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an OS problem (read/write permissions or so), rather than a Selenium problem. It seems someone managed to fix it by changing the owner of the Firefox cache folder.

Try executing these commands:

sudo -s

chown -hR $USER:$USER ~/.cache/mozilla

Please take a look at this and let us know if it worked [Ubuntu - Firefox profile cannot be loaded after upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302891/firefox-profile-cannot-be-loaded-after-upgrade)

Comment: You'de better include the resolution in your answer and use the link as a reference. Changing the link would make your answer invalid.